# Actions is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, class, abstract

I was copying some code from a tutorial book and I have a problem I cannot resolve.

Here is the code:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 class Actions extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            Actions gui = new Actions();
        }

        JButton but1 = new JButton( "Button 1" );
        JButton but2 = new JButton( "Button 2" );
        JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea( 5, 38 ); 

        public Actions()
        { 
            super("Shutdown");
            setSize( 300, 400 );
            setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            add(panel);
            panel.add( but1 );
            panel.add( but2 );
            panel.add( txtArea );
            but2.setEnabled( false );
            txtArea.setText( "Button 2 is Disabled" );
            but1.addActionListener( this );
            but2.addActionListener( this );
            setVisible( true );
        }


        public void actionPerfomed( ActionEvent event )
        {
            txtArea.setText( event.getActionCommand()+"Clicked and Disabled");
            if( event.getSource() == but1 )
            {
                but2.setEnabled( true );
                but1.setEnabled( false );
            }
            if( event.getSource() == but2 )
            {
                but1.setEnabled( true ); 
                but2.setEnabled( false );
            }
       }
}
```

I did exactly as the book stated and just changed the location of `panel.add()` code because it gave a compile error:

```
Actions.java:4: error: Actions is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener class Actions extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a typo, look at your method name `actionPerfomed()` it is missing an `r`. After a change it should run.

Comment: Yes you are right. Weird i commited the same typo twice. So, that constructor has to have that exactly name all the time?

Comment: It is because you implemented the interface `ActionListener`. If you do so, you have to implement all methods that this interface is specify like `actionPerformed`. And true, it's all about naming things exactly in programming :-)

Comment: Okay!! Now i get it. I will be more careful with names next time. I thought it was a random name and because it was not called anyways it was not important. Now i see. Thanks for your help bro.